# Calling an onclick() function from a separate file

Tags: javascript, html, dom-events, src

I have a `onclick` function below:

```
<input type="submit" onclick=logUserIn() value="Log in">
```

which worked fine when I had the function in my script tags

```
<script>

function logUserIn(){
    //does something
};

</script>
```

however I have now extracted this to it's own file called log_user_in.js which is in a JS folder at the same level as my HTML folder.

I have then included this line `<script src="../js/log_user_in.js"></script>` in my html file to find the log_user_in file.

However I now get the error:

> (index):13 Uncaught ReferenceError: logUserIn is not defined

when I try to call the `onclick` method again.

Have I referenced this correctly or what else should I do?

Comment: i think your path is wrong check your JS file is including or not

Comment: You can try to declare the function globally `window.logUserIn = function() { // Code here }`

Comment: @MirzaObaid how can i do that?

Comment: when page loads inspect element or press F12 in chrome and firefox and go to your JS line in code and click on that if all code looks good and align then JS is included if JS not included at first place your code indentation will tell you

Answer (score 0):

[Screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/efBZC.png)

**1.HMTL**

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
    <html>
    <head>
      <script src="js/script.js"></script>
    </head>
    <body>
      <input type="submit" onclick=logUserIn() value="Log in">
    </body>
    </html>
```

**2. js**

```
function logUserIn(){
    alert("Hi ok")
};
```